# Where can I find a TPL dataflow version for 4.0?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library, nuget, tpl-dataflow

I am looking for the .NET 4.0 version of the TPL dataflow library.

The Nuget package has a 4.0 version of the library, but it seems to target .NET 4.5.

I found various references to a 4.0 version, like in this forum:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tpldataflow/thread/6206c714-6dee-4d17-a880-26d0c137a167

But the link mentioned just redirects me to the Nuget page of the library.

Does anyone know where I can find a working version that targets .NET 4.0?

Comment: +1 I thought that Nuget screws only me with claiming the .NET 4.5 packages to be for .NET 4.0!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wrote Steve from the TPL dataflow team about this problem and he responded me with the following download link:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/9/6/F967673D-58D6-4E3F-8CA9-11769A0A63B1/TPLDataflow.msi

This is a CTP version, but the date matches the Nuget package with version number 4.0, so I think it's the latest version that was compiled against .NET 4.0.

Comment: The link is broken!

Comment: @aKzenT: Can you upload TPL Dataflow 4.0 somewhere, and post a link here ?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same experience.  That is, on my Windows XP SP3 (Visual Studio 2010 + .NET 4.)), Nuget is bringing incompatible packages for .NET 4.5 being identified for .NET 4.0. Happened with Reactive (Rx), Async extensions and some more (I did not keep tracks) so I stopped using Nuget.

I've installed  [Async CTP (Version 3)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=9983) + [SP1 to it](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28568) which brought:

- AsyncCtpLibrary.dll
- AsyncCtpLibrary_Phone.dll
- AsyncCtpLibrary_Silverlight.dll
- AsyncCtpLibrary_Silverlight.dll
- System.Threading.Tasks.**Dataflow**.dll
- System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.dll
- System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.Internals.dll

into `<My Documents SubFolder>\Microsoft Visual Studio Async CTP\Samples\` which I now either reference or include into projects.

The .NET 4.5 MSDN docs code examples seem all use `HttpClient` from `System.Net.Http` namespace which I've got from download in code.msdn.microsoft.com [Introduction to HttpClient](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Introduction-to-HttpClient-4a2d9cee)

That is, I've got from the latter:

- System.Json.dll (4.0.20118.13260)
- System.Net.Http.dll (2.0.20118.13260)
- System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll (2.0.20118.13260)
- System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll (4.0.20118.13260)