# Async CTP not working in VS 2010 SP1?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, async-ctp

I downloaded [Async CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=9983) and installed it on my development machine, which has both VS 2010 and VS 2012. The installation seemed to have completed successfully (no errors).

I created a brand new WinForms project (language: VB.NET), and decorated a Form_Load with `Async`.

Problem is that `Async` keyword is not recognized. Did anyone manage to make it work and how?

Doing the same in VS 2012, targeting .NET framework 4.5 works.

**Note:** I don't need any *Silverlight*, *Windows Phone* or even *Web* at this time.

Comment: I tried in a C# project as well, it seems to be unrelated to the language.

Comment: I also tried [How to install the Async Targeting Pack?](http://tribunatek.blogspot.ca/2012/10/how-to-install-async-targeting-pack.html), which tells you can install Async Targeting Pack on VS 2010 via Nuget - Async is not recognized. I successfully installed same Targeting Pack on VS 2012.

Comment: Since you have VS2012 which requires .NET 4.5 to be installed which is an inplace upgrade to .NET 4.0 its unlikely you will be able to install ASYNC CTP I am shocked that the installation actually allowed it.

Comment: @Ramhound: Thanks for your feedback. It worked in my home setup - see my answer below. If you want, you can post your suggestion as an answer, I will upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @Ramhound, I uninstalled everything related to VS 2012 and 2010, then installed 2010 + SP1 + applied Async CTP3. Properly installed Async CTP3 shows a welcome screen and prompts to restart. After that VS 2010 starts supporting the `async` keyword. However, for the full support, it is required to reference a corresponding library from here (platform dependent):

```
c:\Users\%username%\Documents\Microsoft Visual Studio Async CTP\Samples\
```

In my case it was `AsyncCtpLibrary.dll`. Otherwise it will highlight the syntax, but won't compile.

Comment: Probably for distributing your .NET 4.0 app using `async/await`, without .NET 4.5 installed, it is more useful to understand that there is no need to install `Async CTP` (or .NET 4.5) or reference dlls in  `\Samples` dir but simply include `AsyncCtpLibrary.dll` with your project/application

Answer (score 1):

There should be no need to do this.

You already had VS2012 installed, which has full support for `async`/`await`. You can [install `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) to get `async`/`await` support on downlevel platforms, including .NET 4.0.

Comment: In those cases when only VS 2010 is available or it being more preferred (for example, due to stability issues of VS 2012 with WinForms), `AsyncCtpLibrary` is the only way. However, it's good to know there are options when you also have VS 2012 installed. I did not know `Bcl.Async`. Thanks and +1.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary, Microsoft.Bcl.Async is not supported in 2010, per the documentation in the link

Answer (score 0):

I answered it in [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16097562/200449) and if to use more C# 5.0 features without installing .NET 4.5. /VS2012 (which is impossible in Winfows XP) than just `async/await` in my answer to [Where can I find a TPL dataflow version for 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15972581/200449).

Note that .NET 4.0 on machine with installed .NET 4.5 is different from .NET 4.0 with installed .NET 4.5 
In other words you cannot [reliably develop and test .NET 4.0 applications on machine with installed .NET 4.5](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/c05a8c02-de67-47a9-b4ed-fd8b622a7e4a/). The latter is independent on wherher you installed extensions or not